# show message not sent when device is offline and show message is sent when device comes online firebase firestore

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

The app is for messaging, Firebase Firestore used
I want to notify user if message is sent to server or not.
To do this i added "sent (Boolean)" property to message entity , it works fine when i send message as (sent = false)

```
val messageToSend = TextMessage(editText_message.text.toString(), Calendar.getInstance().time,
                            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid,
                            otherUserId, currentUser.name, false, null, false)
            editText_message.setText("")
            sendMessage(messageToSend, channelId)


fun sendMessage(message: TextMessage, channelId: String) {

    FirebaseConstants.chatChannelsCollectionRef.document(channelId)
            .collection("messages")
            .add(message).addOnSuccessListener {
                it.update(mapOf("sent" to true))
            }
}
```

and i control it in my view holder

```
  if (!message.sent) {
            viewHolder.text_message_status_indicator.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_baseline_access_time_24)
        }
```

The problem is when device is online again the message property is not updated (including sent = true)

Please help me with that problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To detect whether a message is coming from the local cache, or from the database on the server, you're better of using `DocumentSnapshot.getMetadata().hasPendingWrites()`. If this property is `true`, the data isn't written to the server yet. If it is `false`, the data has been committed to the server.

For an example of this, see the Firestore documentation on [events for local changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes).

Comment: querySnapshot!!.documents.forEach {
                        val message = it.toObject(TextMessage::class.java)!!
                        message.sent = !it.metadata.hasPendingWrites()                                                                                                                      When i send a message, the messages automatically updated and the last (sent) message document hasPendingWrites() equals to true

Comment: Ok i added MetadataChanges.INCLUDE (to messages' snaplshotlistener) , so works fine btw thanks for help